# Многопоточность, задание из учебника

Tags: java

Задание из учебника:

> Реализуйте следующие методы:
>
> ```
> public static void runTogether(Runnable... tasks)
> public static void runlnOrder(Runnable... tasks)
> ```
>
> Первый метод должен выполнять каждую задачу в отдельном потоке и возвращать полученный результат, а второй метод — все методы в текущем потоке и возвращать полученный результат по завершении последнего метода.

Реализовал первый метод так:

```java
public static void runTogether(Runnable... tasks) {
    for (Runnable task : tasks) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Ума не приложу как реализовать второй, так чтобы сначала все выполнилось, а по завершению последнего метода получился результат, очень признателен за помощь, спасибо!

Comment: `for (Runnable task : tasks) task.run()` ?

Comment: @IR42 если я не ошибаюсь, то тогда методы будут выполняться по очереди и выдавать результат, а в задании нужно что бы они сначала выполнились, а по завершении последнего метода появился результат

Comment: что значит возвращать результат? у вас void функция, она ничего не возвращает, как и run в Runnable

Comment: @IR42 Это хороший вопрос, учебник Хорсманна, я сначала думал что перевод кривой, но нет, в английской версии:
The
second method should run all methods in the current thread and return when the last
one has completed.

Comment: как раз таки тут похоже кривой перевод, так как подразумевается, что вызываемый метод должен возвращаться (заканчиваться) после выполнения последнего runnable. Если с первым методом так же, то значит вам нужно не просто создать и стартануть потоки, а положить их в массив в функции, а потом во втором цикле сделать `join` на каждый поток. `for (Thread thread: threads) thread.join()`

Comment: @IR42 и правда все так, наверно стоит бросать учебники на английском учить в русском переводе, уже не первый раз такая ситуация. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут проблема в нечетко сформулированном условии задачи, а именно в том, что считать результатом.

Так как используется интерфейс `Runnable` и метод `run` возвращает `void`, то в функциональном смысле - результата нет. Результатом роботы являются побочные эффекты т.е. изменения в статических переменных и взаимодействия с внешним миром (т.е. операции ввода-вывода такие как `print` или запись в файл или передача данных по сети). Эти побочные эффекты нельзя отложить, точнее нельзя чтобы метод одновременно и выполнялся, но при этом побочные эффекты были отложены.

Кроме того, это учебная задача и тут не может быть таких сложностей.

Условие следует читать и понимать так "второй метод — все методы в текущем потоке и завершать выполнение по завершении последнего метода" и ответ [IR42](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276430/ir42) абсолютно правильный:

```
for (Runnable task : tasks) task.run()
```

Upd: действительно перевод неправильный.

> and return when the last one has completed.

тут `return` относится к `second method` и имеется ввиду, что `second method should return`, т.е. второй метод должен закончить выполнение.

Comment: Спасибо большое за исчерпывающий ответ!